# Google App Engine + Validation

Tags: google-app-engine, validation, relational-database

I am looking for how to do validation on Google App Engine and I have found only how to do it using Django framework. Ok Django approach is ok but if I have one form and this form have data from few tables what then???
I can not do it like this:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    target_price = db.FloatProperty()
    priority = db.StringProperty(default='Medium',choices=[
      'High', 'Medium', 'Low'])
    entry_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by = db.UserProperty()

class ItemForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ['added_by']

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                '<form method="POST" '
                                'action="/">'
                                '<table>')
        # This generates our shopping list form and writes it in the response
        self.response.out.write(ItemForm())
        self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                '<input type="submit">'
                                '</form></body></html>')
    def post(self):
        data = ItemForm(data=self.request.POST)
        if data.is_valid():
            # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
            entity = data.save(commit=False)
            entity.added_by = users.get_current_user()
            entity.put()
            self.redirect('/items.html')
        else:
            # Reprint the form
            self.response.out.write('<html><body>'
                                    '<form method="POST" '
                                    'action="/">'
                                    '<table>')
            self.response.out.write(data)
            self.response.out.write('</table>'
                                    '<input type="submit">'
                                    '</form></body></html>')
```

Is any easy way to validate form which contain data from few tables or I have to code it alone?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using webapp; I suggest your look at some other 'light-weight' choices for form validation.  Pick one that you like the layout / syntax of.  You'll be able to define complex 'nested' relationships if needed.

- [FormEncode](http://formencode.org/)
- [Formish](http://ish.io/projects/show/formish)
- [Deform](http://docs.repoze.org/deform/)

Answer (score 0):

WTForms has a GAE component [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.appengine)

> WTForms now includes support for AppEngine fields as well as auto-form generation.  The form class can be used as it is or serve as a base for extended form classes, which can then mix non-model related fields, subforms with other model forms, among other possibilities.